# How to read picture path with datagridview c#

Tags: c#

i wanna ask you something , that i have a data grid that show specific data from my database .
this data include a picture box that must show the picture from picture's path that stored in database.The picture path is stored as a string value in column pic in database.But data grid show the all data without showing any picture in the picture box. I want it when i click on data gird cell show me the picture of that row in picture box (reading the picture path from database and show the picture in the picture box) this is my code :

```
private void searchInfo()
{
    con.Open();
    adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from customers where c_name like'%" + c_name_search.Text + "%'", con);
    adapter.Fill(table);

    res_cid.DataBindings.Add("text", table, "id");
    res_cname.DataBindings.Add("text", table, "c_name");
    pcard_type_res.DataBindings.Add("text", table, "c_pic_type");
    picturebox1.DataBindings.Add("text",table,"pic");
    picturebox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    bmb = this.BindingContext[table];
    datagrid.DataSource = table;
     con.Close();
}
```

thank you ...

Comment: `picturebox1.DataBindings.Add("text"` ??

Comment: Use sql parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  A PictureBox does not use its Text property.

Comment: because i saved the picture path in database as a text value , and i want to read the picture path and showing the picture in the picture box.

Comment: Since the PictureBox control doesn't use its Text property, try using the ImageLocation property instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you change the "text" parameter to "Image" or "ImageLocation".

For example:

```
picturebox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("ImageLocation",table,"yourtablename.yourcolumnname",true));
```

Comment: i changed "text" to "ImageLocation" and it woks well ! thank you guys  LarsTech and Tóth Krisztián Gyula :)